# Using Magento API to get Products

Tags: api, magento, product, soap-client

I'm using the Magento API to get product data for products from a certain category from another domain. I have made the API call etc... The code I'm currently using to get the product data looks like this:

```
$productList = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', 7);

foreach ($productList as $product){
    $theProduct = array();
    $theProduct['info'] = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $product['sku']);
    $allProducts[] = $theProduct;
}
```

The code works fine, but it goes extremely slow. When I add the image call to the loop it takes about 50 seconds for the page to load, and that's for a site with only 5 products. What I want to know is the following:

1. Is the code above correct and it's just Magento's API script is very slow?
2. Is the code above not the best way of doing what I need?
3. Could there be any other factors making this go so slow?

Any help would be much appreciated. At least if I know I'm using the code right I can look at other avenues.

Thanks in advance!

**================= EDIT =================**

Using multicall suggested by Matthias Zeis, the data arrives much quicker. Here's the code I used:

```
$apicalls = array();
$i = 0;
$productList = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', 7);

foreach ($productList as $product){
$apicalls[$i] = array('catalog_product.info', $product['product_id']);
$i++;
}

$list = $client->multiCall($session, $apicalls);
```

This now works much quicker than before! The next issue I've found is that the [catalog_product_attribute_media.list](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute_media#catalog_product_attribute_media.list) call doesn't seem to work in the same way, even though the products all have images set.

The error I'm getting in the var_dump is:

***Requested image not exists in product images' gallery.***

Anybody know why this may now be happening? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Magento API is extremly slow. Please provide some info about the volume of data in Magento (number of SKU, store views) and the hardware used...

Comment: @Adam Moss You tried the multicall.  Do you know of a way to get the XML that you generated.  I'm writing an app outside PHP and need the raw SOAP

Comment: @baash05 a bit late here, but you could just run some multiCall commands from PHP and use http://wiki.wireshark.org/XML Wireshark or similar to watch the output

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1. Is the code above correct and it's just Magento's API script is very slow?**

Your code is correct, but the script is slow because (a) the SOAP API is not blazingly fast and (b) you are doing seperate calls for every single product.

**2. Is the code above not the best way of doing what I need?**

If you use the SOAP v1 API or XML-RPC, you can **test [multiCall](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction)**. At first, call catalog_category.assignedProducts to fetch the product ids. Collect the product ids and execute a multiCall call. That should cut the waiting time down quite a bit.

Unfortunately, Magento doesn't provide a nice solution out of the box to deliver the data like you need it. I recommend that you **implement your own custom API call**.

Use a product collection model:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

This will get you a Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection object which can be used to filter, sort, paginate, ... your product list. Iterate over the collection and build an array containing the data you need. You also can generate thumbnails for your products directly while building the data array:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $data[$product->getSku()] = array(
        /* the attributes no need ... */
        'small_image'   => Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')
                                ->constrainOnly(true)
                                ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                                ->keepFrame(false)
                                ->resize(100,150)
                                ->__toString(),
        /* some more attributes ... */
    );
}
```

This should give you quite a performance improvement.

But of course this only is the **tip of the iceberg**. If this solution is not fast enough for you, avoid SOAP and bypass a part of the Magento stack by building **your own API**. This doesn't have to be a complex solution: it could be a simple PHP script with HTTP Basic Authentication which parses the URL for filter criteria etc., includes app/Mage.php and calls Mage::app() to initialise the Magento framework. The benefit is that you have the comfort of using Magento classes but you don't have to go through the whole routing process.

Not to forget, you may **cache the results** because I could imagine that you will show the same products to quite a few visitors on the other domain. Even caching for a few minutes may help your server.

**3. Could there be any other factors making this go so slow?**

There may be some reasons why the calls are *that* slow on your server - but without knowing the volume of your data, your server hardware and the customisations you have done, even a best guess won't be that good.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your tremendously detailed and helpful response. I tried the multicall as you suggested and things are now moving much quicker - see my edit above. For some reason I'm having an issue using the product image call as it keeps returning an error message, while the rest of the data arrives no problem. Any ideas why this would be happening? Thanks again :) !!

Comment: You're welcome! What is the error message? Please also check the logs in var/log and var/report for errors.

Comment: When I var_dump the results I get, each item in the array shows this message: ***Requested image not exists in product images' gallery.***

Comment: I never experienced this error. It's quite weired because from what I see, this error shouldn't be triggered by catalog_product_attribute_media.list. I get a valid response even if I move the image file away. Try to rebuild indexes and caches.

If this doesn't help, the only advice I can give you is to start debugging the method items() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php. The method is responsible for the API call you are using.

Please let me know when you find the reason.

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look into it. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @MatthiasZeis , is it possible to get image url from out of magento box ? for example with android app ? i cant finde any api to return product image url

Comment: @mahdi See http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.list.html if you have further questions please create a new question. I can give longer / better formatted answers there and you may also get help by others.

Comment: can anyone give me suggetion that how will i get OAuth Acces token from magento.. i have consumer_key & secret