# SudzC for magento WSDL does not work properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, magento, sudzc

1. I am using SudzC for generating API for objective-c for the WSDL.
   The problem is the result contains nothing more than empty tag.

   I have found a (temporary!) solution that I get NSData object (of SoapRequest, that holds data fetched from server),convert it to String, which is XML,then parsing it to NSDictionary or NSArray. But now this solution won't work.
2. There is no way to initialise the objects of classes created by SudZC, except using CXMLNode. (I feel very bad when I see other examples those are playing with these stuff)

   for example, if I want to fetch products from the server, I have to pass an object of Filter, but to create an instance of Filter, I need to have an CXMLNode, (I tried to create CXMLDoc containg pure xml, then fetched CXMLElement, then CXMLNode, and passed it to this, but didn't work). Is there any way to handle such problems?
3. I have heard about [multi-call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794234/1369591), how can I implement it in Objective-c?